# Setting up a basic Yii application

Tags: php, yii

Im new to Yii frame work and im on their website and im trying to get my first application working.

from this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app they are asking me to type `% YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp WebRoot/testdrive` into the command prompt

Yii root is at this directory: `E:\Documents\Webdesign\htdocs\yii\`

when i type this

```
  % E:\Documents\Webdesign\htdocs\yii\framework/yiic webapp     
  E:\Documents\Webdesign\htdocs/testdrive
```

into the cmd i get

> '%' is not recognised as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What could be the problem?
can any body help me to get this working?

Comment: Don't type the `%` sign.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this folder using  `cd E:\Documents\Webdesign\htdocs\yii\framework` command

After this type `yiic webapp testdrive` command

Answer (score 0):

In this context here is the meaning of this statement:

`% YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp WebRoot/testdrive`

- `% YiiRoot/framework/yiic` - Change into the directory where you keep the yii library. In this case, you would open your terminal and type: `cd E:\Documents\Webdesign\htdocs\yii\`. Leave out the `%` sign.
- `webapp` - Is the actual command that yiic recognises. It is the one that allows you to generate an application. That means after changing the directory, you would them type `webapp`. Don't press enter until you have typed in the path. So in the end, this part of your command will look like this: `webapp /path/to/where/you/want/to/create/the/application`
- `WebRoot/testdrive` - Lastly, this refer to the directory where you would like your application to be created.

I hope this helps :-)